# Application is only for mdpi (320x480...)

Tags: android

Is it possible in the manifest to indicate that the application is only for mdpi (320x480. ..)? There is a parameter "supports-screens", but there normalScreens means and hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:anyDensity=false`

Note that it will most likely make your app unusable on QVGA screens and very ugly on high resolution displays. Don't use it unless you have a very good reason.

more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html